# Action bar support library - custom view and tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

By using action bar support library, I am trying to put custom view to the action bar along with the tab navigation. But it's not coming as expected.

Below is the code.

```
public class TODOListHomeActivity extends BaseActivity {

private RelativeLayout topbarLayout;
private TextView titleTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    _activity = this;
    // Notice that setContentView() is not used, because we use the root
    // android.R.id.content as the container for each fragment

    // setup action bar for tabs
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    // disable the default title and icon display
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setLogo(null);
    View homeIcon = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    ((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // TODO: The below code may change as per new design
    topbarLayout = (RelativeLayout)LayoutInflater.from(_activity).inflate(getResources().getLayout(R.layout.header_layout), null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(topbarLayout);
    titleTextView = (TextView)topbarLayout.findViewById(R.id.tv_messagecenter);
    titleTextView.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.todolist));
    // new design-end

    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tasks))
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<TODOListFragment>(
                    this, getResources().getString(R.string.tasks), TODOListFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(getResources().getString(R.string.due_today))
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<TODOListFragment>(
                    this, getResources().getString(R.string.due_today), TODOListFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab); 

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(getResources().getString(R.string.completed))
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<TODOListFragment>(
                    this, getResources().getString(R.string.completed), TODOListFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab); 
}

class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
     * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
     * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment
     * @param clz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
     */
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}
```

and the header_layout.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.vl.infotrax"
style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/topstrip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_crossicon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:src="@drawable/crossicon" />

<com.vl.infotrax.components.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_messagecenter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_brodcast_menu"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_crossicon"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="MESSAGE CENTER"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_titlebar"
    custom:customFont="fonts/HELVETIC.TTF" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btn_brodcast_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:background="@drawable/broadcasticon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The output looks like as below.

[image: Layout Link]

I need the tab bar should come below the custom view. How can I do that?

Comment: And your custom view is a Action bar??

Comment: It's not action bar. But I want to use this as custom view for action bar.

Comment: If you remove actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false), did it work?
See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36191, comment 2 (you have used) and 3.

Answer (score 0):

In your case one `ActionBar` is embedded for each tab instead of one for all tabs, but you need `ActionBar` with `ViewPager`, the reverse way. Take a look at this tutorial
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implement-swiping-between-tabs-with-viewpager-in-action-bar-using-sherlock-library/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am not using Sherlock. I am using support library android-actionbar-compat.

Comment: I just mentioned the way you can use to achieve your effect and provided that link as an example, you can use Viewpager with ActionBarCompat Support-Library also, just believe to search on Google :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try some workaround like this ...

firstly set `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)` and then follow undermentioned

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        try{
            View homeIcon = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
            ((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
```